# Powering on Bluetooth 4.0 LE+classic (dual mode)

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I understand that there are two types of devices in Bluetooth 4.0: dual(SmartReady) and single (Smart).

For one of the use cases, I need to use dual mode device.

When a bluetooth is ON in a dual mode device, does it mean that both bluetooth classic and LE are ON? Is there a possibility of Bluetooth LE "on" and bluetooth classic "off" configuration in a dual mode device?

If dual mode device is ON and is in idle state, does it achieve the power savings as that of single mode device ( ie only Bluetooth LE ON)?

Comment: You should add links to documentation about Bluetooth.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can configure what part to be on or off. At least not from the application level.
[This site](http://www.medicalelectronicsdesign.com/article/bluetooth-low-energy-vs-classic-bluetooth-choose-best-wireless-technology-your-application) claims that

> Dual-mode devices will rarely gain in power saving because they need
>   to support both technology implementations; the power savings will
>   only be achieved with the single-mode option.

But it doesn't specify the state in which the device is in.